# Regex everything but strings + use of groups

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to make a whitelist of html tags, here's my code :

```
$string = "<x>-<x>";
$result = preg_match('#^<(?!white1|white2)>.*<(\1)>$#i', $string);
```

But it returns false, and I don't know why. I simplified the regex to avoid confusions, but this is still the same idea.

I want to match every correct tag but the ones I want to keep safe. This regex will go on a preg_replace to erase every matched tag and let the ones I allow.

Thanks for your help in advance !

EDIT: If I find a way to do this with regexs, I'll put the solution here. But for now, I'll do it with `strip_tags()`.

EDIT2: The easiest way I thought to is to parse all the tags and then revert back the ones we allow.

Comment: It looks like you are trying to match identical tag pairs and all that is between them. Why would you want to do that?

Comment: `^<(?!(?:a|p|img)>)([^<>]*)>.*?<\1>$` you could use this regex to match all the tags along with it's content except `a` or `p` or `img` . Then replace all the matched tags with an empty string. You could directly pass this regex in `preg_replace`.

Comment: It can't work, because it doesn't match when it's an authorized element but unvalid (ex: <a><x> won't match)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to eliminate unwanted tags, you can use [strip_tags](http://php.net/strip_tags):

```
$allowedTags     = '<p><a><img>';
$filteredContent = strip_tags($content, $allowedTags);
```

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I wanted to do. I was just searching to deep :p